# How many zeta zeros are needed to accurately calculate five digits for π(1000000), where π(x) is the prime counting function?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

John Derbyshire in his book [PRIME OBSESSION](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Nombres/Derbyshire%20-%20Prime%20Obsession%20-%20Bernhard%20Riemann%20and%20the%20Greatest%20Unsolved%20Problem%20in%20MathematicsAAA.pdf) says on page 343:

> "I’ll round off with a complete calculation of $\pi(1,000,000)$, the
>   number of primes up to one million, using Riemann’s formula -- not for
>   the fun of it, though it is of course great fun, but to make some
>   important points about the error term."

He finds that secondary terms contribute an error of -29.37378.
**My question:** 
How many zeta zeros are needed to find it?

Comment: The phrase that comes after the colon is ungrammatical, and I'm not even sure what it is supposed to say. Could you give the quote from Derbyshire's book?

Comment: http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Nombres/Derbyshire%20-%20Prime%20Obsession%20-%20Bernhard%20Riemann%20and%20the%20Greatest%20Unsolved%20Problem%20in%20MathematicsAAA.pdf

Comment: After search page 344

Comment: Incomprehensible questions should be closed. Voting accordingly.

Comment: @DimitrisValianatos: I suggest adding a bit of commentary to indicate precisely what you are asking; in particular, it would help to screenshot the relevant page of "Prime Obsession."

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: I think this question is interesting enough, and likely non-trivial to a non-number theorist; I suggest forbearance, especially in cases where English might be a second language.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the corrections. I managed to secure 150 million zeros and after several hours of processing I have the following result. -29.373699509746553921692632473197156648 very close to the question. I will verify the calculations and I will try to download more zeros.

Comment: I can not explain it. Unless I make a mistake. The result, up to 190 million zeros, has moved away from the target, compared with the previous one to 150 million. This is -29.3726005971622487672971506613747312740. Very curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Monte-Carlo Approximation of the Prime Counting Function](https://wstein.org/edu/2010/414/projects/stueve.pdf)

This is a numerical study of the dependence of the error $\delta\pi(x)$ in the prime counting function when $N$ zeros $\rho$ of the zeta function are used in the sum $\sum_\rho {\rm Li}\,(x^\rho)$.

Figure 3 shows that for $x=10^{12}$ the error $\delta\pi(x)$ is about 1100 for $N=10^3$ and 300 for $N=10^5$. The error drops by roughly a factor of two when the number of zeros is increased by a factor of ten. More extensive numerical data, with $x$ in the range $10^{10}$ to $10^{17}$, indicates that to reach the precise value of $\pi(x)$ one needs to include about $x^{1.38}$ zeros.

The value $x=10^6$ in the OP is well below this range, but as a first estimate I would conclude that to obtain $\pi(10^6)=78498$ accurate to the last of its five digits one would need $N\simeq 10^8$ zeros.

Comment: well, 10^8 is close to 150 million, as Dimitris reports in the comments

Answer (score -3):

This is a rough estimate , about 101157 zeros . Using Zeta zeros and not zeros that are calculated by XI function or functional equation !

Comment: Even a "rough estimate" needs to be justified somehow ... right now it looks like a randomly chosen integer.